# How to disable default NIC after a PXE BOOT

Tags: nfs, pxe

I am currently using single NFS based PXE boot on eight nodes. I followed the guide on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto

Each nodes has a 1G and 10G network. Both of them are plugged in, i want to use 1G port for IPMI only and 10G for the regular networking.

But as the system boots, it activates both interfaces and assigns DHCP generated ip. How do i disable the first NIC on linux.

```
eno1      # 1G
enp7s0    # 10G
```

I have my BIOS set to PXE from 10G only, and it is working as expected.

So far i have tried following in /network/interfaces (Different trials).

```
iface eno1 inet manual

iface eth0 inet manual

iface enp7s0 inet manual

auto enp7s0    
iface enp7s0 inet dhcp
```

I would rather have eno1 disabled or as backup interface instead of default on.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is here:

```
man 5 interfaces
```

config file to edit:

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

example config;

```
iface bob0 inet static
```

skip providing any ip, the device is static rather than dhcp and has no ip...